# Sort object of arrays by included array with lodash, and find index array

Tags: sorting, object, indexing, lodash

I have an object of arrays, a

```
a.b = [1,4,3]
a.c = ["a","b","c"]
```

I need to sort a in the reverse order of "b", such that the new object will be

```
d.b = [4,3,1]
d.c = ["b","c","a"]
```

I would also need the index array resulting from the sort:

```
i = [1,2,0]
```

Please advise using lodash, thank you. 
O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) to add the current indexes and the numeric values from `b` to an array of [value, index] tuples using `_.map()`, sorting with `_.orderBy()` the tuples according to the value (0 index), and then extract the original indexes with `_.map()` again (1 index). Now you can map `b` and `c` (the other properties) according to the array of indexes, and return the new sorted object.

```js
// order an array by an array of indexes
const mapByIndex = (arr, indexes) => _.map(arr, (_, idx) => arr[indexes[idx]])

const fn = (sortKey, o) => {
  const i = _(o[sortKey])
    .map((n, i) => [n, i]) // store the current index in tuples
    .orderBy('0') // sort the tuples by the number from b
    .map('1') // extract the original index
    .value()

  return _.assign({ i }, _.mapValues(o, v => 
    _.isArray(v) ? mapByIndex(v, i) : v
  ))
}

const obj = {
  b: [1,4,3],
  c: ["a","b","c"]
}

const result = fn('b', obj)

const i = result.i

const d = _.omit(result, 'i')

console.log(d)

console.log(i)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great, thanks. So how do I modify the return statement so that result is actually an object like obj, with result.b = [4,3,1], and result.c =["b","c","a"] ? Thank you. O

Comment: The return value of the function is an object with { b: [], c: [], i: [] }. Run the code snippet

Comment: I did. This is very elegant. My issue is that I need to generate/replace object a with object d, such as d.b = [4,3,1], and d.c =["b","c","a"], so it is natural to have d as output/return instead of its keys. Another issue is that i is not an array (which is what I need). I tried to get i to switch to an array unsuccessfully. I would appreciate if you could output i as an array of indexes, and the fn return as object d, as specified above. The reason I am picky is that I need to translate and modify code above in coffeescript, and getting i and d as specified would help my case. Thank you. O

Comment: Result is an object that contains both the original object data, and the `i` array. You extract it from result. The function needs to return them in a combined way, because a function can only return a single value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modest, if successful, approximate translation of Ori Drori's elegant solution to *coffeescript*:

```
a = {}
a.b = [1, 4, 3]
a.c = [ "a", "b", "c"]

mapByIndex = (arr, indexes) -> _.map(arr, (_, idx) -> arr[indexes[idx]])
i = _.map(a.b, fct = (n, i) -> [n, i])
i = _.sortBy(i,"0")
i = _.map(i, "1")
i = i.reverse()
i = _.mapValues(a, fct = (v) -> if _.isArray(v) then mapByIndex(v, i) else v)

debug _.keys(i)    # b,c
debug _.values(i)    # 4,3,1,b,c,a
debug i.b    # 4,3,1
debug i.c    # b,c,a
```